# How to add more stopwords in nltk list?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have the following code. I have to add more words in nltk stopword list. After i run thsi, it does not add the words in the list

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
import string
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))       
new_words = open("stopwords_en.txt", "r")  
new_stopwords = stop.union(new_word)  
exclude = set(string.punctuation)   
lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()  
def clean(doc):
    stop_free = " ".join([i for i in doc.lower().split() if i not in new_stopwords])    
    punc_free = ''.join(ch for ch in stop_free if ch not in exclude)
    normalized = " ".join(lemma.lemmatize(word) for word in punc_free.split())   
    return normalized
doc_clean = [clean(doc).split() for doc in emails_body_text]
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code-- it makes no sense the way you have it.

Comment: `new_stopwords = stop.union(new_word) `  should surely read `new_stopwords = stop.union(new_words)`? Also   `new_words = open("stopwords_en.txt", "r") ` returns a file object, so you're adding the file object to the stopword list, not the contents. You want something like  `new_words = open("stopwords_en.txt", "r").readlines() ` surely?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do things blindly. Read in your new list of stopwords, inspect it to see that it's right, *then* add it to the other stopword list. Start with the code suggested by `@greg_data`, but you'll need to strip newlines and maybe do other things -- who knows what your stopwords file looks like?

This might do it, for example:

```
new_words = open("stopwords_en.txt", "r").read().split()
new_stopwords = stop.union(new_words)
```

PS. Don't keep splitting and joining your document; tokenize once and work with the list of tokens.